# Android push Notification with Google Play

Tags: android, notifications

In my project I want to give a push notification to the user if there is an update new version on Play store. I have to notify every time the user turn on phone. Is there any way to do this? Please help me on this

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: What's the point of implementing this, when play store checks updates automatically?

Comment: With all due respect to the moderator, this IS a 'real' question, and one for which I was also seeking an answer (which is given below).  I, for one, was happy to find this question and the answer and do not understand why it was closed.

Answer (score 3):

As StoneBird mentioned, if your app is on the Play Store (which it sounds like based on the question text), it'll notify or auto update for you.

If your app is somewhere else (another market, or is loaded without a market), this type of push notification could be useful...

To push notifications to the user, you can use Google Cloud Messaging. It's a free service that allows you to push notifications to a service in your app (via a pre-defined broadcast receiver). That service can then present a notification to the user about the available update.

See [docs](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) for details on how to implement it.

I happened to give a lecture on this tonight for my Android development class. I've just now edited out most of the questions and posted a [video clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUYlFDdAVIo) on youtube. The code [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxF4_-k2zB3mQlFSYmhoOTNQWXc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Nice addition. I didn't thought maybe OP means checking app outside the store.

Comment: Since his title includes "Google Play", it was a safe assumption ;)

Comment: nice job, thank you verymuch ^o^